# AngularJS adding html5Mode broke redirectTo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

After adding

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true,  requireBase: false});    
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

to my app.js to get rid off a "hash-bang" URL case it broke working

```
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

in the `$routeRovider`.

`<base href="/">` is set in the index.html

Any clue how to get it fixed? I'm new to AngularJS (I'm using version 1.6.5)

Comment: version of angularJs? also what did you have before in prefix?

Comment: @alphapilgrim 1.6.5

Comment: angular routing will break if html5mode is set. In order to achieve the routing  properly you need to have some redirection logic on server side.  for ex `urlrewrite` for .net

Comment: please see this [article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode). should help shed some light on this.